# VueJS difference between methods and functions?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I didn't manage to find much on this, what's the difference between using a method and declaring a function in the script tag?

**example.vue**

```html
<script>
export default{
    methods: {
        testfunction1(){
            ...
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.testfunction1();
    }
}
</script>
```

compared to

```html
<script>
export default{
    methods: {
        ...
    },
    mounted(){
        testFunction1();
    }
}

function testFunction1(){
    ...
}
</script>
```

PS: If they're both legit, what are their uses cases? - When to use both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put simply, the `testFunction` declared outside of `methods` will not have access to the Vue instance via `this`.

For example, this will not work

```js
function testFunction() {
  console.log(this.someDataProperty)
  // "this" is the module scope and someDataProperty will not be defined
}

export default {
  data: () => ({ someDataProperty: 'whatever' }),
  mounted () {
    testFunction()
  }
}
```

If your functions are *pure functions*, then there's no problem declaring them outside of `methods`.

---

Methods also become part of your component's API so you could have something like this in a parent component

```html
<ChildComponent ref="child"/>
```

```js
this.$refs.child.someMethod()
```

Functions declared outside `methods` would not be available in this manner.

---

Another difference mentioned by [ssc-hrep3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233827/ssc-hrep3) is that only methods can be called from your component's template

```html
<button @click="someMethod()">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Right! Great point. So will there be a use case for non-method functions? Should I separate them as "helper" functions if they do not need access to `this` and only include them in methods as required? Underlying question - What would be a good/more correct way to structure my code?

Comment: That's how I've used them in the past, ie _helpers_, _utility_, etc. It's pretty subjective but if you want to keep your component's API clean, moving junk out of `methods` is one way to do so. It might also help with unit testing if you can test your helper functions in isolation

Comment: You can also directly use the method in the same component's template: `<div @click="someMethod()"></div>` and even pass inline variables of a `v-for` as method parameters: `<div v-for="item in list"><div @click="someMethod(item)"></div></div>`

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 excellent point. If you don't mind, I'll add that to the answer

Comment: Just go for it :)